# How to setup monitoring for JMeter Load Test in Linux machine?

Tags: linux, jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I already tried the options to setup monitoring on Linux with these references:

[1. Monitor server resource utilization with JMeter SSHMon Listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-monitor-server-resource-utilization-with-jmeters-sshmon-listener)

[2. Monitor server health performance using JMeter Perfmon Agent](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)

But these two options is not working for me. For SSHMon, I already troubleshoot but not found the solution, here's the issue description: [JMeter SSHMon Listener issue error - I/O and Swap not captured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68752343/jmeter-sshmon-listener-issue-error-i-o-and-swap-not-captured).

For JMeter Perfmon, Server Agent installed successfully but I'm not able to resolve this issue due to firewall at server side, the other team don't want to configure the existing defaults for firewall, so I opt to SSHMon, but still not working.

We plan to extract monitoring Linux server manually, if Windows, can use [Windows Performance Monitor](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-performance-team/windows-performance-monitor-overview/ba-p/375481), but how about linux? Which is the best implementation for this? By using [Third Party Linux Software Monitoring tools](https://www.netadmintools.com/linux-monitoring-software/#wbounce-modal) or simply by [Linux Command tools](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/top-linux-monitoring-tools.html)? If with Command Tools, possible to set scheduler in this?

Appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. For the PerfMon Agent - if the "other team" is not willing to open default port 4444 - you can bind the agent to another port like:

   ```
   ./startAgent.sh --udp-port 1234 --tcp-port 5678
   ```

   replace the ports with the one(s) which are open in your Linux server

   also be aware of [SSH Tunelling option](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-setup-ssh-tunneling/), like you can forward the port 4444 from the remote machine to the port 4444 on you local machine and connect to `localhost:4444` with the Perfmon Metrics Collector Listener
2. For the SSHMon - stating that it "doesn't work" sounds weird because it just executes the command provided by **you** and plots the returned values in the "over-time" chart. If you cannot come up with a proper command - it's rather your problem, not JMeter or its plugin problem, if you're not comfortable with sar - there are alternative options like `cat /proc/swaps` or [`free`](https://linuxize.com/post/free-command-in-linux/) commands which give you the swap file utilization. Also there are programs like [mpstat](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mpstat) or [iostat](https://linux.die.net/man/1/iostat) which might be easier to use and parse. See [How to Monitor Server Resource Utilization with JMeter’s SSHMon Listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-monitor-server-resource-utilization-with-jmeters-sshmon-listener) article for sample commands.

If you need further support you need to indicate the exact metric(s) and the anticipated values (percentage of total, absolute value, if you go for the absolute values - which unit you would like to see, etc)

Comment: Thanks sir. For the monitoring part, i use LoadRunner only to extract the monitoring and actual test run using JMeter